# Using name attributes as parameters in Python (Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to pass a name attribute as a parameter in a function, to make it more generic.

For example, I'd like to modify this function:

```
@classmethod
def count_events_per_day(cls, myqueryset):
    return myqueryset.filter(
        created__range=(a,b))
```

to make something like:

```
@classmethod
def count_events_per_day(cls, myqueryset, attr_name): # attr_name would be passed as a string
    return myqueryset.filter(
        attr_name__range=(a,b))
```

Is there a way to do this?
I searched on SO but I suppose the keywords I use are not relevants since I can't find any answer.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand. So you want your attribute name to be automatically modified?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac That's it. As I need to use this method with different attributes (not `created` only), I'd like to avoid to write N times this method for the N attributes I have.

Comment: What type is attr_name? Is it just a string?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Nope. It's an attribute of an object. My class is `Event` and one of its attributes is `created`.

Comment: @DavidW. Could you please show us how you call `count_events_per_day`, and what are the values of arguments? And why couldn't you pass `'created'` as `attr_name`?

Comment: @Bunyk That was the reason I did not answer the question. Its a little ambiguous.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Names are usually the strings. Because what else they could be? Integers or lambdas? That would be strange. :)

Comment: @Bunyk Yes, but as you can see, that it is of type event.

Comment: Sorry about this, attr_name in the parameter of the function I'd like to write IS a string.. I just wanted to say that in a Django context, the attribute is not a string, it's an attribute ('keyword').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, because you could pass arguments to function from dictionary:

```
@classmethod
def count_events_per_day(cls, myqueryset, attr_name):
    return myqueryset.filter(**{
        attr_name + '__range': (a, b)
    })
```

UPD: Adding link to answer with explanation of double-star syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/816449

Comment: This creates a `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression` :(

Comment: @DavidW. What do you pass as attr_name? `'created'` ?

Comment: Because, usually such error means that you used in name of argument some characters which are not allowed in identifiers, like `'.'`, or `'+'`...

Comment: `attr_name` is not a string, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ahh yes, of course I'm passing a string. I just wanted to say that attr is not a string in a Django context. Sorry. Btw, it seems to work, but I don't understand how ^^ I continue to test something and I go back! Thanks :)

Comment: This works well, thanks a lot for this. May I ask you to add some explanations about the syntax you're using to help beginners like me to understand concepts instead of just copy-past the answer? :)

Comment: @DavidW. Sure. This is already explained by others, I just added link.